# Power Automate Error moving CSV from SharePoint to Google Drive

Tags: csv, sharepoint, google-drive-api, power-automate

I'm running into an issue with my Power Automate Flow. I'm trying to push a CSV file from a SharePoint folder to a folder in Google Drive. Creating the CSV is fine, but when I try to push the CSV there seems to be a (unreasonable) limit on the size of the CSV I can push.

As the file already exists and I am simply PUSHING the file, not recreating it, surely it shouldn't hit any limits? This file is only 52MB!
[The Flow I have - previous step is just a scheduler](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AAlgt.png)
[error message I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oWSyR.png)

Comment: 52428800 Bytes = 50 MB (in binary)

Comment: Still, that surely is not a large file to be pushing?

Answer (score 0):

Look at this link and try with copy to google drive

https://sharepains.com/2019/05/31/copy-large-files-with-microsoft-flow/